# Why is pivot_longer is creating duplicate rows in my data frame?

Tags: pivot, tidyverse, distinct, data-cleaning

I am using pivot_longer to clean up my data frame and it created three duplicate rows for each plant species.

Here is a sample of the data frame:

```
latin_name           plant_type treatment       `ounces per plot` weight            `grams per plot`
   <chr>                <chr>      <chr>                       <dbl> <chr>                        <dbl>
 1 Agastache foeniculum wildflower tx._one_rate               0.021  wt_per_plot_one              0.609
 2 Agastache foeniculum wildflower tx._one_rate               0.021  wt_per_plot_two              1.22 
 3 Agastache foeniculum wildflower tx._one_rate               0.021  wt_per_plot_three            1.83 
 4 Agastache foeniculum wildflower tx._one_rate               0.021  wt_per_plot_four             2.44 
 5 Agastache foeniculum wildflower tx._two._rate              0.0430 wt_per_plot_one              0.609
 6 Agastache foeniculum wildflower tx._two._rate              0.0430 wt_per_plot_two              1.22 
 7 Agastache foeniculum wildflower tx._two._rate              0.0430 wt_per_plot_three            1.83 
 8 Agastache foeniculum wildflower tx._two._rate              0.0430 wt_per_plot_four             2.44 
 9 Agastache foeniculum wildflower tx._three._rate            0.0645 wt_per_plot_one              0.609
10 Agastache foeniculum wildflower tx._three._rate            0.0645 wt_per_plot_two              1.22
```

And here is the code chunk I used:

```
library(tidyverse)
seed_rate1 <- seed_rate1%>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("tx"),
    names_to = "treatment",
    values_to = "ounces per plot")%>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("wt"),
    names_to = "weight",
    values_to = "grams per plot")
```

And here is 12 rows and all columns of the data using dput():

```
seed_struct <-
  structure(structure(
    list(
      latin_name = c(
        "Agastache foeniculum",
        "Agastache foeniculum",
        "Agastache foeniculum",
        "Agastache foeniculum",
        "Agastache foeniculum",
        "Agastache foeniculum",
        "Agastache foeniculum",
        "Agastache foeniculum",
        "Agastache foeniculum",
        "Agastache foeniculum",
        "Agastache foeniculum",
        "Agastache foeniculum"
      ),
      plant_type = c(
        "wildflower",
        "wildflower",
        "wildflower",
        "wildflower",
        "wildflower",
        "wildflower",
        "wildflower",
        "wildflower",
        "wildflower",
        "wildflower",
        "wildflower",
        "wildflower"
      ),
      treatment = c(
        "tx._one_rate",
        "tx._one_rate",
        "tx._one_rate",
        "tx._one_rate",
        "tx._two._rate",
        "tx._two._rate",
        "tx._two._rate",
        "tx._two._rate",
        "tx._three._rate",
        "tx._three._rate",
        "tx._three._rate",
        "tx._three._rate"
      ),
      `ounces per plot` = c(
        0.021,
        0.021,
        0.021,
        0.021,
        0.042975207,
        0.042975207,
        0.042975207,
        0.042975207,
        0.06446281,
        0.06446281,
        0.06446281,
        0.06446281
      ),
      weight = c(
        "wt_per_plot_one",
        "wt_per_plot_two",
        "wt_per_plot_three",
        "wt_per_plot_four",
        "wt_per_plot_one",
        "wt_per_plot_two",
        "wt_per_plot_three",
        "wt_per_plot_four",
        "wt_per_plot_one",
        "wt_per_plot_two",
        "wt_per_plot_three",
        "wt_per_plot_four"
      ),
      `grams per plot` = c(
        0.609,
        1.218,
        1.827,
        2.437,
        0.609,
        1.218,
        1.827,
        2.437,
        0.609,
        1.218,
        1.827,
        2.437
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-12L),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
  ))
```

Unable to figure out how to fix this i tried to use distinct() with no luck either...I am new to R so I suspect there is something in the pivot_longer that I am not doing correctly. If anyone has any input I would greatly appreciate. I am new to R so very specific/ easy to understand responses would be much appreciated!

Comment: Share the sample of your data with `dput`, it make easier to reproduce

Comment: @ViníciusFélix is this better? I've never used dput. See edits at the bottom. Essentially I am trying to clean this df to make a few graphs using ggplot

Comment: You name your data `seed_struct` but your _code chunk_  uses `seed_rate1`. Where does this come from? In your code you look for colnames which start with either `tx` or with `wt`, but there are no such colnames.

Answer (score 1):

You name the data `seed_struct` but use in the code `seed_rate1` for the `pivot_longer`. As it is not clear where `seed_rate1` comes from I will work with `seed_struct` from your `dput`.

`cols = starts_with()` in `pivot_longer` selects columns with names starting with whatever you put in. If you want to use `treatment` - the variable which contains categories with names starting with `tx` - in `pivot_longer` that does not make sense, as this variable is already in the long format.

If you want to combine the variables `treatment` and `weight` in a long format, you can do this:

```r
library(tidyverse) 

seed_struct |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(treatment, weight))
#> # A tibble: 24 × 6
#>    latin_name           plant_type `ounces per plot` grams per plo…¹ name  value
#>    <chr>                <chr>                  <dbl>           <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#>  1 Agastache foeniculum wildflower            0.021            0.609 trea… tx._…
#>  2 Agastache foeniculum wildflower            0.021            0.609 weig… wt_p…
#>  3 Agastache foeniculum wildflower            0.021            1.22  trea… tx._…
#>  4 Agastache foeniculum wildflower            0.021            1.22  weig… wt_p…
#>  5 Agastache foeniculum wildflower            0.021            1.83  trea… tx._…
#>  6 Agastache foeniculum wildflower            0.021            1.83  weig… wt_p…
#>  7 Agastache foeniculum wildflower            0.021            2.44  trea… tx._…
#>  8 Agastache foeniculum wildflower            0.021            2.44  weig… wt_p…
#>  9 Agastache foeniculum wildflower            0.0430           0.609 trea… tx._…
#> 10 Agastache foeniculum wildflower            0.0430           0.609 weig… wt_p…
#> # … with 14 more rows, and abbreviated variable name ¹​`grams per plot`
```

As 2 columns are transferred into a longer format your original DF of 12 rows turns into one with 24 rows.

The other thing you might have in mind is maybe making the DF wide instead of long. This can be done with `pivot_wider` by choosing the 2 variables with their values.

```
seed_struct |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = treatment, values_from = `ounces per plot`) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = weight, values_from = `grams per plot`)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 9
#>   latin_name     plant…¹ tx._o…² tx._t…³ tx._t…⁴ wt_pe…⁵ wt_pe…⁶ wt_pe…⁷ wt_pe…⁸
#>   <chr>          <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 Agastache foe… wildfl…   0.021  0.0430  0.0645   0.609    1.22    1.83    2.44
#> # … with abbreviated variable names ¹​plant_type, ²​tx._one_rate, ³​tx._two._rate,
#> #   ⁴​tx._three._rate, ⁵​wt_per_plot_one, ⁶​wt_per_plot_two, ⁷​wt_per_plot_three,
#> #   ⁸​wt_per_plot_four
```

This makes your original DF into one which combines all interesting variables into one row.